# Chrome Developer Console not working

Tags: javascript, developer, chrome

I'm on 
https://c.cs8.visual.force.com 
and 
https://na30.salesforce.com

The chrome dev console works in log in screen, but as soon as I log in, the dev console stops working.

More specifically, if I were to type in something simple as

```
Console.log("hi")
```

nothing happens.

Comment: In my experience the console is sometimes affected by cash on your machine. Can you try the same from other machine to narrow down the options?

Comment: Presume using the defined `console` instead of the undefined `Console` doesn't help?

Comment: My coworker, using a different machine is having similar issues. He's using IOS,  I have Ubuntu, so not OS dependent either.

Comment: Is the problem only in those specific orgs? What if you try a fresh dev org? Is it possible that something has redefined what `console` is?

Comment: I've been experiencing this too, since about a week ago. First page load of any force.com or salesforce.com page is fine, but a refresh or clicking a link (essentially any subsequent page load) seems to break the console. Regular scripts still run, I can use console.log and whatnot within my static resources, but code executed from the console does nothing and doesn't return anything. I don't encounter this issue on Firefox.

Comment: I have switched from Chrome to Chromium and the dev console there is working. 

We have some chrome specific javascript code running, so Firefox was not an option. :'(

Comment: I too noticed this today. Console works fine on other pages but not on any apex page. Also, if change the context from "top" to some other extension context, it works again. but does not works for top context.

Comment: `console.info` works.

Answer (score 6):

I too experienced this issue as reported [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136355/salesforce-breaking-javascript-console). If you are using Chrome version 52, try updating to version 53. Many thanks to [@plusplusben](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/996/plusplusben) for finding this fix.

Answer (score 0):

Check this page: https://superuser.com/questions/1106091/google-chrome-52-js-console-is-not-working-on-some-websites

I tested, if there is apex:commandButton on the page, then the console doesn't work.