# Salesforce Breaking Javascript Console?

Tags: javascript, hack

### Problem Statement

I worked out a neat script to run in the Chrome DevTools console to make a configuration process faster. I went into my sandbox to reproduce the behavior so I could write it up in a Q&A post on here. Then I found something really strange and disturbing. It seems like Salesforce may have somehow disabled console output (at least in some sandboxes).

I did some digging and it looks like [Facebook pioneered a strategy to disable the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools). The basic gist of their approach is:

```
Object.defineProperty(console, '_commandLineAPI', { get : function() { throw 'Nope' } })
```

But that doesn't seem to be what Salesforce is doing.

---

### Observed Behavior

**Here is how I normally expect the console to behave:**

[image: Standard Console Behavior]

**Here's what it should look like after applying the hack:**

[image: Hacked Console Behavior]

**Here's what it looks like in my sandbox:**

[image: Sandbox Console Behavior]

**The console does still seem to be logging system messages:**

[image: System Logging]

---

### Conclusions & Questions

There is no output. I'm at a loss to why it's broken. I've searched around and most of the Stack Overflow posts ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240523/console-log-messages-not-showing-up-in-chromes-javascript-console)) have to do with the filter settings, which clearly aren't the cause of these missing logs. The log output isn't being filtered out, it's just completely swallowed somewhere.

I can also confirm this is not a browser issue, as I'm able to use DevTools normally everywhere else, even in a new tab on the same window. The behavior is consistent across the `Home Page`, `Object Tabs`, `Detail Pages`, and `Visualforce Pages` (except when `showHeader="false"`). The behavior presents on `cs45` and `cs19`, but not `test.salesforce.com` or `login.salesforce.com`.

- Why is my console broken?
- How can I fix it?
- Is Salesforce engineering this behavior?
- Should I expect this behavior in production soon?

**Update**

Now seeing this information on `na20` as well, so I also see it hitting production.

Comment: When did this start? I just used the console yesterday in both sandboxes and production. I'll see if I can see the same behavior once I hop on a computer.

Comment: @cricket I've never really tried using the console in any sandbox before today. So far I've confirmed the issue on `cs45` and `cs19`. It does not seem to affect `test.salesforce.com` or `login.salesforce.com`. I'll edit that into my question.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've confirmed the behavior on cs45 using Chrome 52.0.2743.116m. It doesn't happen on na2.

Comment: It only appears to affect the "top" frame. Others, such as sessionserver202.html are unaffected. Using a Chrome incognito window to disable plugins makes no difference.

Comment: Right, my production instance is also unaffected (that's where I ran my snippet that saved me from carpal tunnel).

Comment: Related: [Chrome Developer Console not working](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/133220/102)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but it's lacking in description and I can hardly add all this detail there!

Comment: I noticed this happening as well with Chrome 52.. Rolling back to Chrome 51 seemed to resolve it for me. I don't know what, specifically, the problem is but for me it had to do with Chrome 52

Comment: This started happening with me as well going back a month or so ago when I was on the beta channel. It still continues. Currently on v52.

Comment: It's interesting.  I've experienced this issue off and on recently not really paying much attention to it.  After reading your post I opened Chrome DevTools and experienced the issue you are getting.  Then I closed the DevTools and re-opened them and everything was working as expected.  (this was on a Task detail page).

Comment: Thank you for the analysis.  This has been painful and it's good to know that SF doesn't seem to be trying to intentionally disable the console.

Comment: Not working for me in Firefox 51.01 - not sure if its JS or a visualforce problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this issue is only affecting Chrome 52 and is related to this bug. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=636409

The workarounds for now are to use Chrome 53 (or greater) or another browser. Also, turning off the standard Salesforce header resolves this issue.

Comment: Sweet, that works. Unfortunate that 53 is still in Beta but I guess it's not a huge problem.

Comment: Chrome 53 is currently available at https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html

Comment: It looks like 53 is now the [stable release](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2016/08/stable-channel-update-for-desktop_31.html). No need to run the Beta any more.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this exact problem and by chance finally stumbled across this page.  Which was super helpful to me and WILL work.

However, I was just speaking with a co-worker of mine and he said he was also having this problem and came up with a different solution that I felt was merit to post here on this thread.

If you use the 'Salesforce Lightning Inspector' from the Chrome Web Store, it will fix the problem.  When you are in the chrome console, instead of using the filter option 'Top' there will be a 'chrome-extension://[stuff]' option.  If you choose this option you can use the console again.  It also comes with additional features that I have not explored yet as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused because of the visualforce main.js over riding the window.Map function.
Following the steps in this Article resolves the issue
[Native JS Map prototype is overwritten in Visualforce page w/ a header](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103924/native-js-map-prototype-is-overwritten-in-visualforce-page-w-a-header)

Comment: Yeah the posted fix does not work for any standard pages.

Comment: Also, overwriting `Map` doesn't cause the same behavior. This answer is completely unrelated to the question at hand.