# Embedded VF Page Not Rendering on Page Layout

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, page-layout

I have a Visual Force page that I created that contains a dynamic pick list field I want to add to a page layout. The VF page uses a standard controller for "Account" and has an extension. I am having an issue with the dynamic pick list field displaying on the Account page when I add it to the page layout.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="Account_QuoteTemplatesExtension" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:detail />
    <apex:form >
        <apex:PageBlock mode="edit">
            <apex:PageBlockSection title="Quote Template Selection" columns="1">
                <apex:PageBlockSectionItem >

                    <!-- Label for picklist -->
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Quote Template" for="quoteTemplates" />
                    <!-- Dynamic picklist of values (quote templates) -->
                    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedTemplate}" size="1" id="quoteTemplates">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!TemplateOptions}" />
                    </apex:selectList>

                </apex:PageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:PageBlockSection>
        </apex:PageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Class Controller:

```
global with sharing class Account_QuoteTemplatesExtension {

private final ApexPages.StandardController controller;
private final Account record;
private final Id recordId;

public String selectedTemplate {get; set;}

public Account_QuoteTemplatesExtension (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.controller = stdController;
    this.recordId   = this.controller.getId();
    this.record     = [SELECT id, name FROM Account WHERE Id = :this.recordId LIMIT 1];
}

// Returns list of quote template options
public List<SelectOption> getTemplateOptions() {
    // Initiate option list
    List<SelectOption> tempOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    // Get all quote templates from metadata
    List<Quote_Template__mdt> quoteTemplates = [SELECT MasterLabel, Template_Id__c FROM Quote_Template__mdt];
    // Add all options to select option list
    for (Quote_Template__mdt temp : quoteTemplates) {
        tempOptions.add(new SelectOption(temp.Template_ID__c,temp.MasterLabel));
    } 
    return tempOptions;   
}
```

}

I have added the VF page in a section called "Quote Template"
[image]

But the section renders blank on the Account record page
[image]

The VF page renders fine in the preview, but will not show up embedded on the page layout. 
[image: Preview]

Is this an issue with my controller?

Comment: Check `Profile` access for the page. Navigate to `Setup` > `Develop` > `Visualforce Pages`. Your page should have  a `Security` link next to it. Only `Profiles` with access will be able to view the page. Though I'd think it would throw an exception, not be blank.

Comment: Also...Why are you embedding the `<apex:detail />`...It doesn't make any sense to nest like that.

Comment: I just checked, and I have the page enabled for System Administrator, which is the profile that I am currently using. Also `<apex:detail />` was leftover from an attempt at solving my issue. It's removed-- but still renders blank.

Comment: I would strip out *all* content at first and then replace it with `<apex:outputText value="Hello World" />` or some such. If it renders, add tags back in incrementally until it breaks. Also attributes like `mode="edit"` could be the cause. If that pared down page still doesn't render, something else is up.

Comment: I just replaced my VF code with the following: `<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:PageBlock >
            <apex:PageBlockSection title="Quote Template Selection" columns="1">
                <apex:PageBlockSectionItem >
                    
                    <apex:outputText value="Hello World" />
                   
                </apex:PageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:PageBlockSection>
        </apex:PageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>` but the section appears blank still.

Comment: Also just checked to see if there were any other VF pages overriding the standard layout and confirmed that there are no overrides. Hmm not sure where to go from here

Comment: Maybe your page needs something in the header. Try removing all the `<apex:page>` attributes *except* `standardController`.

Comment: I have tried with the following taking out additional attributes and tags: `<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <p> Hello World! </p>
</apex:page>` but the page still renders blank on the page layout.

Comment: Just curious, what happens if you use that page in a custom button instead?

Comment: I created the button and clicked on it and it takes me to the rendered VF page! I guess the problem is occurring when I embed the VF page in the page layout

Comment: Seems obvious, but can you also verify that you are including the correct page? Maybe you accidentally included the wrong one. Also, what if you create a fresh page and reference that instead?

Comment: I've checked multiple times to make sure I am using the right page and I have tried creating a new one as well. I've been getting messages saying '_Your browser privacy settings have prevented this page from showing some Visualforce content. To display this content you need to change your browser privacy settings to allow "Third Party" cookies from the domain c.cs44.visual.force.com. Alternatively, if your browser is Internet Explorer, you can add c.cs44.visual.force.com to your trusted sites list in the security options page._'

Comment: However, I'm using the latest Chrome, added the website to cookie and site data exceptions,  and the box to prevent third-party cookies is unchecked.

Comment: Hmm, I had some [weird issues with Chrome 52](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136355/salesforce-breaking-javascript-console). Try updating to version 53 (beta) and see if that helps.

Comment: It looks like it worked! But I have to click on the button that takes me to the VF page first. After I click that button to get to the link, it renders on the page layout page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may actually be related to bugs in Chrome's build for version 52. Try installing version 53 (which is still in [Beta](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html)) and you may resolve those security issues.

Answer (score 0):

If your referring any field in visual force page please check that particular field permission is enabled for logged in user or not.